# LM393 Ref voltage does not seem to work

Tags: analog, comparator, lm331

I am trying to build a comparator using the LM 393.
Just a basic design where I my Vref 3V is produced by 100/150 Ohm voltage divider.
The input signal is a pulse from a geiger sensor as below:

[image: Input Signal]

[image: LM393 Output]

However, the output signal is not a square wave of duration of ~100us as expected (when Vin > Vref). The duration is rather for the full duration of input pulse, as shown in the second picture:

I am wondering what I might be doing wrong. The Vref does not seem to affect at all. I have tried changing the Vref to 2V, 2.5V etc. The other thing to note is, when I apply a continuous power supply to the input,ie, a DC sweep from 0-5V or 5V-0V, I can observe the cutoff at 3V/Vref. The output goes high or low in accordance to the input. It only does not seem to work when i am trying to process the signal pulse from my sensor.

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

ADDITIONAL Details.

My High Voltage circuit has stopped working, so I am unable to use the Geiger output at this moment.
This is the LM393 connections. I had already used a 10K resistor from output to VCC for the graphs in the previous post.
Unfortunately I am unable to do dual trace as none of the other 3 channels are working in the oscilloscope unit. (I swapped probes and channels. The problem is with the channels for sure). So, I have taken some new pictures.

[image]

In order to really test the LM393, I have generated a Sinusoidal signal using R-2R ladder and arduino. This time around, the LM393 did seem to behave characteristically. I have elevated the Vref to 3.5V by adjusting the voltage divider.
Please note the 3 pictures below.

1. You can note the Vref at 3.5V
2. This is the sinusoidal signal fed as Vin
3. The output trace. You can clearly see, if you follow the time divisions, the width of the square wave corresponds to that part of the Sin signal above 3.5V. I have tried this by varying the Vref, and the width of the square wave does change accordingly.
   So I am led to believe that previously it must have been the nature of the GM output pulse responsible for the unnatural behaviour of the LM393.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated. May not be the right place, but any hint on how to process pulse signals from a geiger counter into TTL levels?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: LM393 is open drain and needs an output load to V+. This MAY be fooling you. PLEASE provide links to relevant items. [LM393 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm193.pdf). and a circuit diagram.

Comment: Can you show us both traces together (ie. dual trace display)? Also please provide a schematic and/or a photo of the setup.

Comment: Thanks Russell and Bruce. I am adding some new details.